# Kendo uI datepicker disable type and selection

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to disable typing and selecting a date in kendo ui datepicker. Unfortunately the following code only disable typing but still allow the user select the date.

```
 $('#CreateDate').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Is there any to achieve this, please advise, thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable the control by passing `false` into its [`enable`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datepicker#methods-enable) method:

```js
$("#CreateDate").data("kendoDatePicker").enable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in the 1 Answer is a typo.

Here the way how it works for me using Kendo UI jQuery:

**$('#yourHtmlId').data("kendoDatePicker").enable(false);**